# How to fuzify a crispy variable

Tags: clips, fuzzy-logic

I read some examples about how to fuzify a variable in FuzzyClips. I tried it by myself but i got some strange behaviour:

```
(deftemplate age-template
0 100 years ; Universe
(
(young (15 0.75) (17 1) (19 1)) 
(mature (18 0.75) (25 1) (30 0.25)) 
(adult (30 0.5) (40 1) (50 0.75)) 
(old (40 0.25) (50 0.75) (65 1) )
)
)

(deftemplate person

(slot name (type STRING))
(slot age (type INTEGER))
(slot city (type STRING))
)

(deffacts start
(person (name "John") (age 25) (city "London"))
(person (name "Mike") (age 55) (city "London"))
(person (name "Eva") (age 35) (city "London"))
)


(defrule fuzzify
    (person (name ?name) (age ?age))
=>
    (assert(age-template (?age 0.0) (?age 1.0) (?age 0.0))) 
)
```

[image: result]
I don't know exactly what those "???" really mean and why each fact is being retracted after being asserted. I also have another doubt, i tried to print not only the age, but also the name and the age of each person with:

```
(defrule fuzzify
    (person (name ?name)(age ?age))
=>
    (assert (person-is ?name age-template (?age 0.0) (?age 1.0) (?age 0.0)))    
)
```

But i got error "a function name must be a symbol".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved it. I read that getting ??? is a common behaviour. So the solution is:
Create another deftemplate that will be the structure of the person name with their fuzzy age. In the rule's consecuent, instanciate the deftemplate asserting someone's name with the fuzzy age.

```
(deftemplate age-template
0 100 years ; Universe
(
(young (15 0.75) (17 1) (19 1)) 
(mature (18 0.75) (25 1) (30 0.25)) 
(adult (30 0.5) (40 1) (50 0.75)) 
(old (40 0.25) (50 0.75) (65 1) )
 )
 )

 (deftemplate person

 (slot name (type STRING))
 (slot age (type INTEGER))
 (slot city (type STRING))
 )

 (deftemplate fuzzyfication
 (slot nameperson (type STRING))
 (slot agefuzzy (type FUZZY-VALUE age-template))
 )

  (deffacts start
 (person (name "John") (age 25) (city "London"))
 (person (name "Mike") (age 55) (city "London"))
 (person (name "Eva") (age 35) (city "London"))
 )


 (defrule fuzzify
 (person (name ?name) (age ?age))
 =>
 (assert(fuzzyfication (nameperson ?name)(agefuzzy (?age 0.0) (?age 1.0) (?age 0.0)))) 
  )
```

And the execution returns:

[image]